# Can anybody show me how to properly install Funtoo Linux on Btrfs filesystem (EFI)?

Tags: installation, arch-linux, efi, gentoo, btrfs

Well, I've tried to install Funtoo Linux and Arch Linux on Btrfs as root filesystem (in my notebook, so it's EFI) but I just could not reach this objective even following every kind of tutorials I've seen in the internet. When trying to install Funtoo Linux, everytime when I tried to chroot it fails with a message of "Illegal instruction (core dumped)". Of course I have not much knowledge about Btrfs, so I ask to somebody help me.

Obs: I usually make 3 partitions; one for EFI, one for swap and other for root. I also create subvolumes for root, var and opt folders. Some guy in a tutorial made a subvolume for usr/portage folder but did not explain why.

Comment: For first time, use a easy distribution like Ubuntu, Mint, Manjaro etc. See the Arch Linux installation here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide.

Comment: I have already installed both Arch and Funtoo (but on xfs) and I really am not interested in another distro. I want to customize my environment and do that in others distros like Ubuntu is almost impossible.

Comment: What does Arch show? it has a `btrfs-progs` package.

Comment: When I tried to do this on Arch the dump error did not occur but I could not boot the system after the reboot because something went wrong. I just installed Funtoo with Ext4 anyways; it's ok now.